# Solidity function overloading and selectors -- member not unique

Tags: solidity, interfaces

I have the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract test{

mapping(bytes4 => bool) internal supportedInterfaces;
uint public a;

function test() public{
          supportedInterfaces[this.transferFrom.selector] = true;
  }

  function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceID) external view returns (bool) {
        return supportedInterfaces[interfaceID];
  }


  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public{
     a = 1;
  }

  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data) public{
    a = 2;
  }

}
```

But I get the error:

> Member 'transferFrom' is not unique after argument dependent lookup.

So how do I refer to the selector (or two different ones) in the test function?

Edit:  https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1256   --does this issue mean that it's not resolved?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if there's a better way, but you can compute the function selectors directly:

```
bytes4(keccak256("transferFrom(address,address,uint256)"))
```

and

```
bytes4(keccak256("transferFrom(address,address,uint256,bytes)"))
```

Comment: You forgot to also convert the function signature into `bytes` :
Should be:
`bytes4(keccak256(bytes("transferFrom(address,address,uint256))"))`
-
`bytes4(keccak256(bytes("transferFrom(address,address,uint256,bytes")))`

Comment: Casting the string in bytes is not necessary here.You can hash the string with `keccak256` directly, 

like -> `bytes4(keccak256("transferFrom(address,address,uint256)"))`

instead of ->  `bytes4(keccak256(bytes("transferFrom(address,address,uint256)"))`

It is slightly cheaper in gas, as casting to `bytes(...)` add 84 extra gas units.